# CoreImage CIImage Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

Core Image is not working:

```
    let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "image", withExtension: "png")

    let begainImage = CIImage(contentsOf: fileUrl!)

    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
    filter?.setValue(begainImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter?.setValue(0.5, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    let newImage = UIImage(ciImage: (filter!.outputImage)!)

    self.imageView.image = newImage
```

Comment: first check that fileUrl is not nil, with `if let` please check that image.png exists in your project

Comment: check the way that you add your image to your project remember check copy if needed option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you wrote :

```
filter?.setValue(0.5, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
```

instead of

```
filter?.setValue(0.5, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
```

Comment: Still App Crashing

Comment: in which line do you have the crash?

Comment: let begainImage = CIImage(contentsOf: fileUrl!)

Comment: Do you have a problem with loading your image. Try at first with a different images and different formats, because the code syntax is correct. 

Or try at load a UIImage first and then convert it to a CIImage

Comment: let image = UIImage(named: "Luna.png")
 let begainImage = CIImage(image: image!)

Comment: Now its working i dont know that happen to CIImage(contentsOf: